За что заблокировали участника Fox Fox?
Его заблокировали на месяц, это значит, что его заблокировали второй раз. А за что?

Вы наверное его просто не знаете. А вот я не раз с ним сталкивался в комментариях. Довольно вспыльчивая личность.

Многократное нарушение норм поведения.

Да он не адекватный  - «существует только два мнения: моё и неправильное». И хоть что ему пиши, хоть как пытайся донести информацию, всё тщетно - как итог от него прилетает минус, оскорбления, но своей неправоты так и не признает (ещё и обижается ахахах). В общем, в баню его, хоть немного отдохнём без его экспертной токсичности;))

Теперь понятно.

@Amgarak, я буду скучать по его капсу  Эмоции прям через экран передавались))

@Chaos_Sower это было прикольно первые пару раз, но последнее время мягко говоря - стало надоедать. Да и эти капипасты из гпт "я не пробовал, но вот мне гпт насоветовало, попробуйте посмотрите" - мне прям поджигали пукан.

@Chaos_Sower кстати да, я тоже с интересом следил за всеми его рамсами, было весело)

очень обидно, что новых участников, которые хоть капельку "выходят из нормы" сразу блокируют, а те, кто давно на сайте и пишут "всякое разное" остается в тишине, а новые - те, что встречают напор обидевшись просто уходят с ru.SO... порой, когда видишь к примеру https://i.sstatic.net/n8tNKhPN.png, и видишь, что юзер удален, понимаешь, что мы потеряли участника, просто потому, что начали диалог не с правил https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct норм поведения...Так что тут говоря "вспыльчивая личность"/"не адекватный" /итд Важно помнить о https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct

@Dev18 почитайте пожалуйста описание метки [tag-meta:профиль-участника] прежде чем её добавлять. Она про страницу профиля, а не про блокировку

@Kromster, активности пользователя на сайте ???

@Dev18 не вырывайте из контекса - "Для вопросов, связанных со страницей профиля участника, содержащей список всех его вопросов, ответов и журнал активности пользователя на сайте."

@Kromster, прям над вашим комментарием до моей правки, я добавила размышление. Вы оставите свой отзыв по этому мнению?

@Dev18 звучит как явное преувеличение - "что новых участников, которые хоть капельку "выходят из нормы" сразу
блокируют"

@Kromster, Вы, возможно, вырвали мою мысль из контекста. Я имела в виду, что иногда встречаются случаи, когда новые участники, которые чуть-чуть отклоняются от общепринятых норм, сталкиваются с непропорционально жёсткой реакцией. Разумеется, это не означает, что всех без исключения блокируют, но такие случаи встречаются, и это может отпугнуть новичков.

Идея, которую я несу, и мысль это, что важно стремиться к равному отношению ко всем участникам, независимо от стажа на сайте, и всегда соблюдать нормы поведения, чтобы не потерять перспективных новичков, которые на первый взгляд могут порой казаться "не такими ценными"
